# hiding the calendar on datapicker

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, calendar

```js
$('.year').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  onOpen: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").addClass('hide')
  },
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  }
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy dd',
  onClose: function(dateText, inst) {
    var month = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-month :selected").val();
    var year = $("#ui-datepicker-div .ui-datepicker-year :selected").val();
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(year, month, 1));
  }
});
```

```css
.hide {
  display: none; 
}

.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  <!--  display: none; -->
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input class="year" type="text" id="" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="" />
```

What i want is when i click on year it will not show calendar.

I could put it like

```
.ui-datepicker-calendar {
  display: none;
}
```

But if i do this this will affect all date pickers. What i need is to specify the date picker where i need to hide the calendar

Comment: Definitely this will hide all datepicker. You have to put the inline css for a specific datepicker which is to be hide

Comment: @MayankPandey that is why i have the `onOpen: function(dateText, inst) {
    $("table.ui-datepicker-calendar").addClass('hide')
  },` it was a wild guess but it didnt work. how to add hide on open of specifc input of datapicker?

Answer (score 0):

jQuery UI Datepicker widget doesn't have *onOpen* option, you should use option *beforeShow*.

Also you should add your class to *$(this).datepicker('widget')* or use *setTimeout()* within *beforeShow* because this event starts before *table.ui-datepicker-calendar* is created.

```js
$('.year').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy',
  beforeShow: function(input) {
    $(this).datepicker('widget').addClass('hide-calendar');
  },
  onClose: function(input, inst) {
    $(this).datepicker('widget').removeClass('hide-calendar');
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, 1));
  }
});

$('.datepicker').datepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  showButtonPanel: true,
  dateFormat: 'MM yy dd',
  onClose: function(input, inst) {
    $(this).datepicker('setDate', new Date(inst.selectedYear, inst.selectedMonth, inst.selectedDay));
  }
});
```

```css
.hide-calendar .ui-datepicker-calendar{
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.8.9/themes/base/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<input class="year" type="text" id="" />
<input class="datepicker" type="text" id="" />
```